# PPPoE dialer on iball extreme 150M router is hhowing 'CHAP Authentication Failed'?

Tags: networking, ethernet, pppoe

I'm using Triple Play service which uses PPPoE over regular ethernet port. I have connected the RJ-45 to WAN port of the router and configured correct uname and pass in its settings. I have cloned MAC of my PC because my ISP uses MAC addresses to authenticate. However when I dial using my router, it does not connect at all. I have got the following logs from my router. What could be the possible cause? I'm not able to get any similar logs from my system windows7 pppoe dialer which connects flawlessly.

Logs - http://pastebin.com/5DGeJXrQ

Answer (score 0):

The logs show its 'CHAP authentication failed'. CHAP works in the way that authenticator sends a CHAP challenge which is hashed along with key and send back to authenticator. If this hash value matches with the hash computed by authenticator (which has the shared key). The authentication works. Some ISP encodes MAC or hostname(which they note when you connect for the first time) etc in CHAP challenge. This allows them limit the use to only one network device. So you must get the credentials updated so that your new router can connect with its own attributes.